# Hyperlink Not Accepting '&' Symbol

Tags: hyperlink, arcgis-portal, operations-dashboard

I am using Esri's Operations Dashboard and trying to insert a hyperlink into the Feature Details widget. The problem appears to be the '&' symbol. When the hyperlink is clicked, the '&' sign disappears in the url and I receive an error message.

To account for the HTML I entered this:

[image]

Which became this:

[image]

And resulted in this:

[image]

And displayed this error message:

[image]

Comment: It is very difficult to read from your screenshot. Just to confirm you are using this `&amp;` (&amp followed by a semi-colon) and not by a colon, correct?

Comment: Correct, I am using a semi-colon after the &amp

Comment: Using HTML encoding on a URL isn't likely to work, but using [URLencoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after much trial and error I have figured it out.

I had to use a combination of URL encoding and HTML encoding.

In the end, there were 3 symbols the software/browser/server was having trouble with: '&', '{', and '}'

For the '&', HTML encoding was needed.

For the '{', HTML or URL encoding was accepted.

For the '}', URL encoding was needed.

In order to get the hyperlink to work I had to delete everything and then go back and enter the new url into the system.

The end encoded result: http://www.mycompany.net/records/personal/details.asp?taxyear=2015&amp ;ppt=A&amp ;acct=%7Bacct%7D

I added the spaces between amp ; so this site would not automatically translate it to '&'. The actual encoded url does not contain those spaces.

And after all of that, I needed to submit the hyperlink, click ok for the widget, then go back into the edit mode again and once more click ok. If I only did the process once, then my hyperlinked field did not translate to the actual account. For some reason, going through the process twice jumpstarted the link and my {acct} was linked to the number.

Thank you to all who helped and Vince, Thomas B, user30184 and Mintx in particular for steering me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use %26 instead of the &

Tool to encode for example http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

If you can edit in plain html you could use this just for the href.

Comment: Yes, URLencoding is the way to go here

Comment: Thanks; I didn't know that tool existed. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I entered in the encoded string and once clicked, the browser url was missing the '&'s which resulted in the error message displaying again.

Comment: You may need to escape the '%' as '%%' or '\%', depending on how the data is processed

Comment: But isn't & used here as a part of a http query string and therefore there should be no need to url-encode it?

Comment: I have tried both %% and \% but neither worked. My '&' is still missing.

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the actual URL link and not just the URL text?